# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed when deleting from a database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am currently trying to delete items from my database using JDBC but am getting an error that I can not figure out how to get away. The error is:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

Here is the java:

```
    System.out.println("Connecting database for Delete...");
    Integer deletedCount = 0;

    Statement deleteStatement = null;
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
        deleteStatement = conn.createStatement();
        String selectDelete = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE end <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)";

        ResultSet rs = deleteStatement.executeQuery(selectDelete);

            while (rs.next()) {

                String eventid = rs.getString("id");
                String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = " + eventid;
                deleteStatement.executeUpdate(deleteSQL);
                deletedCount++;
                System.out.println(deletedCount);
            }
       System.out.println("Completed Delete! "+ deletedCount +" deleted!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }
```

What I am doing here is first selecting all the items that date has already passed and setting it to a result set. I then go through a while loop in an attempt to delete them from the database. It runs through one time and get the error which I will fully put below. Would I need to create a new delete statement every time I go through the loop? I can not figure a way to properly do this.

Here is the full error:

```
Connecting database for Delete...
Database connected!
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
at JDBC.deleteOverDueEvents(JDBC.java:56)
at EventJSON.main(EventJSON.java:31)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:743)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6313)
at JDBC.deleteOverDueEvents(JDBC.java:45)
... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why SELECT, LOOP and DELETE when

```
String deleteSQL= "DELETE FROM table WHERE end <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)";
Statement deleteStatement = conn.createStatement();
deleteStatement.executeUpdate(deleteSQL);
```

would work more efficiently

Comment: That would make more sense. I was doing the loop to get the number of deleted items. Can you return it just from that statement?

Comment: Yep, see the return value from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

Comment: Perfect, didn't know that returned.

Answer (score 1):

When the line

```
deleteStatement.executeUpdate(deleteSQL);
```

is executed, then `ResultSet rs` is automatically [closed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.

---

But you can solve this simply by running

```
String deleteCmd = "DELETE FROM table WHERE end <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)";
int deletedCount = deleteStatement.executeUpdate(deleteCmd);
```

instead of selecting the records and deleting each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because your deleting the row while looping to the result set and your logic is totally wrong. Your selecting all ids with  "end <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)" then delete it afterward. Why not delete it all in the first place? like this "DELETE FROM table WHERE end <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)". If you need to get the count to a select statement first then to the delete query.